# ASP.NET RSS Feed giving style sheet error

Tags: asp.net, rss

Hey im wondering why I am receiving the following error in my rss feed

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

from a bit of research ive done this is becuase I dont have a stylesheet attached. But I have done plenty of RSS Feeds before and normally they pick up the default look and feel as below

http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/ongoing.atom

I am just wondering why this one is giving the above error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the content-type of your feed is not correct, so IE is treating it as raw XML.

What is the URL of your feed? What browser are you using?

the tbray.org URL returns a 
 Content-Type: application/atom+xml

What is the content-type header returned by your misbehaving feed?

('wget --save-headers ...' may be useful)

Comment: no. not the answer. both IE and FF pick it up as RSS even if the content-type is plain text/xml.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you need to make sure you declare your namespaces.

Take tim bray's feed and save it locally as test.htm.  bring it up in firefox and it will show nicely.  now if you remove a namespace in  that's being used like :thr the content will disappear.  if you remove the base namespace you'll just get plain text.